# How to publish all custom classes from theme in Tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css, vite

I create component library and want to publish all custom classes like "text-primary", "text-secondary", "bg-primary", "text-primary-100", "text-primary-200", and so on...

Tailwind takes all classes which are used in the code, but I need all custom classes generated too, even which using them.

My tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#FF9225',
        primaryDark: '#EF7C09',
        primaryLight: '#FFC68C',
        secondary: '#14487E',
        secondaryLight: '#EDF7FF',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  prefix: 'bui-',
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
};
```

My build command:

```
"build": "tsc --p ./tsconfig-build.json && vite build && npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css",
```

I would appreciate any help! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use the plugin `tailwind-safelist-generator`. It allows you to load classes by a pattern or directly from the classes itself.

You can use it like :

`tailwind.config` :

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
// If you are using Typescript, sadly 'tailwind-safelist-generator' does not support typescript for now ... You will need to use @ts-ignore
// You can also create `tailwind-safelist-generator.d.ts` and `declare module`
// @ts-ignore
import tsg from 'tailwind-safelist-generator';

export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    tsg({
      path: 'path/to/your/safelist.txt',
      patterns: [
        'bg-{colors}', // load every bg colors classes
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Then in your `content` you just need to add the path to your `safelist`.

However, there is more pattern you can use here is the doc : [tailwind-safelist-generator](https://github.com/spatie/tailwind-safelist-generator)

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you, it was a new package for me. I just generated needed classes. I will wait for more answers to accept you answer. Thank you one more time :)